# Excel 2013 auto copy formulas to non-sequential rows

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Can I auto copy a formula down rows when the formula references data in non-sequential rows? The formulas in column B on **Sheet1** are set up as follows:

```
B1 references Sheet2!B1
B2 references Sheet2!A1
B3 references Sheet2!B2
B4 references Sheet2!A2
```

Comment: What do you mean by *auto copy* the formula? Are you referring to using the formula fill feature, or something else?  What exactly have you tried, and where are you stuck with accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you tried filling in the formula in B1 and B2, highlighting them, then using the fill box to drag downward?

Answer (score 0):

Set `B1` (on `Sheet1`) to

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!R" & INT((ROW()+1)/2) & "C" & MOD(ROW(), 2)+1, FALSE)
```

and drag/fill down. 
The first argument to `INDIRECT()` is a string that looks like

- Row 1: `Sheet2!R1C2`
- Row 2: `Sheet2!R1C1`
- Row 3: `Sheet2!R2C2`
- Row 4: `Sheet2!R2C1`

The second argument, `FALSE`, tells `INDIRECT()` to treat the cell reference
part of the first argument as being in "`R1C1`" format;
i.e., as `Rrow#Ccolumn#`. 
So the above are interpreted as

- Row 1: `Sheet2!B1`
- Row 2: `Sheet2!A1`
- Row 3: `Sheet2!B2`
- Row 4: `Sheet2!A2`